# ¿Como insertar comillas a las key en una consulta con "JSON_OBJECT"? de mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Utilizo esta consulta:

```
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id",pd.id_pedido_detalle,"cantidad",pd.cantidad,"precio",pd.precio_pedido))
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
[{id: 991, cantidad: 1, precio: 10}, {id: 992, cantidad: 1, precio: 20}]
```

Intento convertirlo, con **javascript**, a un **json** y me arroja el siguiente error:
[image]

**[En este enlace](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a6313950c8e44d9d91f73078b84bf096)** utilizo *JSON Editor Online*, para ver el porque, y es porque faltan las "" en las llaves.

**[En este enlace](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1c2b3b167bb047839dfb237aee8e355d)** le agregue las comillas a las llaves para demostrar que es solo eso lo que falta.

Comment: entonces ya respondiste tu pregunta?

Comment: @shadow la pregunta es **¿Como insertar comillas a las key en una consulta con "JSON_OBJECT"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como desconozco la estructura de tus tablas, te respondo con el siguiente ejemplo

1. Declaro la estructura de una tabla con una columna de tipo `JSON`

---

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
   data JSON NOT NULL
);
```

2. Posterior inserto algunos valores en la columna `data`

---

```
INSERT INTO demo(data)
VALUES

('{"backend": true, "frontend": "maybe"}'),
('{"backend": false, "frontend": "si"}');
```

3. Ahora para devolver esos valores, hago la siguiente consulta

---

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("backend", data->'$.backend', "frontend", data->'$.frontend')) as D FROM demo;
```

Como puedes revisar estoy usando la sintáxis acortada de `columnaPrincipal->'$.columnaNombre'` para armar el JSON que me devolverá mi consulta

4. Resultado final

---

```
[{"backend": true, "frontend": "maybe"}, {"backend": false, "frontend": "si"}]
```

Ahora si lo pasas por un `JSON Validator` como: https://jsonlint.com/

Te lo reacomoda así:

```
[{
    "backend": true,
    "frontend": "maybe"
}, {
    "backend": false,
    "frontend": "si"
}]
```

Y al final nos indica que es una estructura `JSON` válida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que esta bien respondida, el problema creo que es el framework que uso (Laravel), debe de estar eliminando las comillas de las llaves :/

Comment: lo dudo compañero, sería buena idea que desde el inicio menciones detalles como que estas usando Laravel @PabloContreras

Comment: puedes probar metiendo esta consulta completa dentro del query Builder asociado a una variable, posterior hacer un `dd()` para ver que te retorna

Comment: Si, no creía que el framework afecta, por eso no lo coloque. Intente a tu manera y tampoco me coloca las comillas de las llaves. Por eso supongo que es el framework.

Comment: añade de manera completa como estas construyendo la consulta en Laravel @PabloContreras